# Hosting WebSite in IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created a sample website . I am using Linq as Model. I am trying to host my website in IIS 5.1.But when i am trying to login (acceesing page via IIS 5.1) i am getting follwing error:

```
Cannot open database "WCF" requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user .
```

WCF is the name of the database.
My authentication section web.config is

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Default2.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Security and authentication setting which i have in IIS is
[image]

My connectionString is

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WCFConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCF;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any idea why is it happening?
please help.

Comment: The login that fails is the one you use to connect to the database with. What's your connectionString look like?

Comment: Does IUSR_ExXP have login rights to your database? When you use integrated security, it will use whatever account the IIS process is running as - which in this case seems to be IUSR_ExXP.

Comment: Thanks, @J.Steen , I am able to solve my issue.

Comment: Then I'll post the comment as an answer. I should have done that to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `IUSR_ExXP` have login rights to your database? When you use integrated security, it will use whatever account the IIS process is running as - which in this case seems to be `IUSR_ExXP`.